# Build nested dictionary based on relationship coefficients

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have 3 variables, a,b and c, and 3 coefficients a_b, a_c and b_c. I want to use these to build a nested dictionary rels that would be the following:

```
   a   b    c
a  1   a_b  a_c
b a_b  1    b_c
c a_c  b_c   1
```

So for example:

```
rels['a']['b']=a_b
rels['b']['c']=b_c
rels['a']['a']=1
```

and so on

Clearly,  I can make this by hardcoding:

```
rels = {}
rels['a']={{'a':1,'b':a_b,'c':a_c}}
```

and so on. I was wondering if there was a more elegant/efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you want this in a dictionary and not, say, a `pandas` DataFrame?

Comment: I would use it for element-wise lookup. rels['a']['c'].

Comment: A DataFrame can also do this: `df.loc['a', 'c']`

Comment: I guess either would work in this case? What is the advantage of one vs. the other?

Comment: The advantage of a DataFrame is that `pandas` can natively read your data in its original format. `pd.read_csv(f, sep=r'\s+', index_col=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the data and use a dictionary comprehension:

```
import re
s = """
   a   b    c
 a  1   a_b  a_c
 b a_b  1    b_c
 c a_c  b_c   1
"""
new_s = [list(filter(None, re.split('\s+', i))) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))] 
new_data = {a:dict(zip(new_s[0], b)) for a, *b in new_s[1:]}
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'a': '1', 'b': 'a_b', 'c': 'a_c'}, 'b': {'a': 'a_b', 'b': '1', 'c': 'b_c'}, 'c': {'a': 'a_c', 'b': 'b_c', 'c': '1'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your list and for every item item in list you can find the relation of that item(or each variable) with all the variables in the list and store them in another list
In Simple Way - 
`

```
var = ['a','b','c']
rels = {}
for item in var:
    rel = {}
    for i in range(0,len(var)):
       if(item == var[i]): 
           rel[item] = 1
       else:
           rel[item] = item+"_"+var[i]
    rels[item] = rel
```

Comment: This is clever. I realise that in the 3 variable case this is slight overkill, but would be helpful if I did it with more.